# In GCD are serial queue synchronous by asynchronous operation Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am using a serial queue with QoS background

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue1", qos: DispatchQoS.background)
```

Assigning one jobs synchronous, and two jobs asynchronous:

```
func serialTask() {
    serialQueue.sync {
        for i in 0..<10 {
            print("", i)
        }
    }
    serialQueue.async {
        for i in 20..<30 {
            print("⚪️", i)
        }
    }

    serialQueue.async {
        for i in 101..<120 {
            print("", i)
        }
    }
}
```

All 3 jobs are executing sync one after another, but last two jobs are async. Are async jobs sync in serial queue's.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let me see if I can clarify the difference between `async` vs. `sync`.

A couple of changes that I will employ in my example:

1. I will use Instruments’ “Points of Interest” to show when tasks are running rather than `print` statements. (See WWDC 2019 [Getting Started With Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/?time=1234).) This way we can see the behavior graphically.

   I will post a simple “Point of Interest” event signpost (Ⓢ) when dispatching something and I will wrap the dispatched task in a “Region of Interest” (a horizontal bar) to graphically illustrate the duration of some process.
2. I'll change your `for` loops to be a `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)`, simulating some time consuming process. If you just have a quick `for` loop, things will happen so quickly that it will be impossible to discern what's really happening with the threads.

So, consider:

```
import os.signpost

private let pointsOfInterest = OSLog(subsystem: "GCD Demo", category: .pointsOfInterest)

func tasks(on queue: DispatchQueue) {
    pointsOfInterestRange(with: "tasks(on:)") {
        os_signpost(.event, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "1") // first Ⓢ
        queue.sync { self.oneSecondProcess(with: "1") }

        os_signpost(.event, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "2") // second Ⓢ
        queue.async { self.oneSecondProcess(with: "2") }

        os_signpost(.event, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "3") // third Ⓢ
        queue.async { self.oneSecondProcess(with: "3") }
    }
}

func oneSecondProcess(with staticString: StaticString) {
    pointsOfInterestRange(with: staticString) {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    }
}

func pointsOfInterestRange(with staticString: StaticString, block: () -> Void) {
    let identifier = OSSignpostID(log: pointsOfInterest)
    os_signpost(.begin, log: pointsOfInterest, name: staticString, signpostID: identifier)
    block()
    os_signpost(.end, log: pointsOfInterest, name: staticString, signpostID: identifier)
}
```

That is just like your example, but rather than `print` statement, we have signposts statements, yielding the following graphical timeline in Instruments’ “Points of Interest” tool:

[image]

So, you can see that:

1. The `tasks(on:)` function, on the bottom, issued the `sync` dispatch, the first Ⓢ signpost.
2. It waits for the `sync` task, “1”, to finish before continuing, at which point it issues the two subsequent dispatches, the second and third Ⓢ signposts (which happen so quickly in succession that they overlap in the graph).
3. But `tasks(on:)` doesn't wait for the two `async` tasks, “2” and “3”, to finish. As soon as it finished dispatching those `async` tasks, it immediately returns (hence the `tasks(on:)` range stops immediately at that point).
4. Because the background queue was serial, the three dispatched tasks (“1”, “2”, and “3”) run sequentially, one after the other.

If you change this to use a concurrent queue, though:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "...", attributes: .concurrent)
```

Then you can see that the two `async` tasks now run concurrently with respect to each other:

[image]

This time, `task(on:)` dispatches the `sync` call, waits for it to finish, and then, only when that `sync` call is done can `seriesOfTasks` proceed to dispatch the two `async` calls (in this case, not waiting for those to dispatched tasks to finish).

As you can see, the `async` and `sync` behavior is different. With `sync` the calling thread will wait for the dispatched task to finish, but with `async`, it won't.

---

There are two main conclusions that one can draw from the above:

1. The choice of `sync` vs `async` dictates the behavior of the current thread (i.e. should it wait for the dispatched task or not).

   And, as a general rule, we would generally avoid calling `sync` from the main thread when doing anything time consuming (because that would end up blocking the main thread).
2. The choice of a serial queue vs a concurrent queue dictates the behavior of the work you dispatched, namely can it run concurrently with respect to other tasks on that queue, or will they run consecutively, one after the other.

Answer (score 4):

Synchronous and asynchronous execution has nothing to do with the underlying queue. Synchronous execution means, that the calling thread must wait until the block is finished. Thus, the second block is *enqueued after* the first block has finished. Asynchrounous means, that the caller **must not** wait for the completion of the block. Thus, the third block is *enqueued* directly after the preceeding `serialQueue.async` statement while the second block is still running or even waiting for execution.

At the end of your function `serialTask()` it is guaranteed that the first block is executed. The second and the third blocks are enqueued, but it is not sure if they are executed, running or even waiting for execution. Since you're using a serial queue, it is sure that the second block is executed before the third block.

You may check the asynchronous execution of the two last blocks by adding

```
serialQueue.async {
    print "sleep"
    sleep(10);
    print "awake"
}
```

before the two calls of `async`, and you will observe the following:

1. The first block will be executed immediately, and `sleep` will be printed immediately.
2. The execution of `serialTask()` takes considerably less than 10 seconds.
3. `awake` is only output after 10 seconds (surprise, surprise).
4. The second and the third block are also executed after 10 seconds, so long after `serialTask()` ended.

This *late* execution of the two blocks means *asynchronous*. If you're moving your first (synchronous) block to the end of `serialTask()`, the following will happen:

1. `sleep` will be printed immediately.
2. The execution of `serialTask()` takes approximately 10 seconds. It is finished after the synchronous block at the end is executed.
3. `awake` is only output after 10 seconds (surprise, surprise).
4. The second and the third block are also executed after `awake` is printed out.

Comment: Ok but last two async tasks are not executing async the behaviour is same as sync.

Comment: @salmansiddiqui: The two blocks _are_ executed asynchronously. You deduce from your unfortunate example that it is universally valid. That leads you to the wrong conclusion. Please see my edits.

Comment: here you have added sleep but the behaviour is same it will just wait for some time and execute.

Comment: @salmansiddiqui This answer is spot-on great, and clemens provided the tools to prove it.  I was saying much the same thing, but far less effectively and with no proof.  I’ve upvoted this one.

Comment: @Smartcat how a late execution is considered as Async

Comment: @salmansiddiqui By late execution, he means execution that in all likelihood starts after serialTask() ends, or certainly has no requirement to start before serialTask() ends.  Thus it's async because it's not synchronized to the other operations of serialTask() that may follow it's request to execute asynchronously.  If you cross your eyes, two people standing before you could look like one person, but that doesn't mean they are.  You claimed that "All 3 jobs are executing sync one after another" but that's not true. They just appear to be when all you're relying on are your print statements.

Comment: @Smartcat you mean to say two async task is executing parallel internally but print serially..?

Answer (score 0):

So the sync task runs immediately, then when it completes, you add two async tasks to that queue, *and then your method returns.  *Those two tasks will then get processed in order, *as soon as that queue is idle*.

So if you had any pending async tasks in that queue before this method is called, those tasks will run before your two async tasks.